# Alternative for spliting large dataset in R

Tags: r, split, bigdata

I am using split() for split a dataset of more than 15M lines. The common split() works but consumes a lot of time. Then I made a function to split the dataset by number of rows for, then, give that resulted list to be splitted (this is the essential split, a split by one of the variables) in parallel using snow.

It works a lot faster now but for 15M lines it crashs because this model consumes a lot of memory (I am using 3 machines of 16GB memory each).

Do you know any alternative for doing this split without using so much memory? I tried ff package but the split function doesnt work equally as if worked with data.frame. I tried the split-apply-combine of ffbase package but I just need the split part and I didnt find a way to use only the split step.

Thank you

Comment: Seems like your splitting activity, will almost certainly create a copy of the data. That is probably too much to hold in memory. I'd probably try to process small chunks one at a time from the data, instead of create all small chunks at once, then processing them.

Comment: I am trying with 3 machines using one core each. Do you mean to stop parallel processing? Then it will take a lot of time again.

Comment: ffdfdply from package ffbase should return a data.frame inside the FUN argument. If this is not the case in your example, you could try to mimic the internals of ffdfdply which basically sets up a list of positions, one for each split group and saves this in ff. If your split positions are possible in RAM, why don't you just put this 1 column in RAM and use which to select your data from ff into RAM. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for helping @jwijffels. I tried which but it is very slow. Can you explain with more details what you suggested? I also built a list of ffdf (transforming a list of data.frame in a list of ffdf) and tried to apply this in parApply() of snow but I get the error: nodes produced errors; first error: incorrect number of dimensions. The structure of ffdf is different from data.frame.